# How to get meaningful message for failing Specs2 test on all elements of a collection?

Tags: specs2

I have a list of files `exampleProblems`, to each of which I want to apply a method and check that it doesn't throw an exception. The problem is that I don't get a good failure message from Specs2. I need to find out which element caused the problem. I already tried adding an `aka`, but with no success.

Here is the code:

```
def is: Fragments =
    "parse all example uai files" ! (exampleProblems must contain((p: String) => {
      Problem.parseUAIProblem(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(p)).aka(p) must throwAn[Exception].not
    }).forall)
```

And here is the message I'm getting:

> java.lang.Exception: There is 1 failure Got the exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: variables are
>   not ordered increasingly
>
> at
>   vultura.fastfactors.UAIParserTest$$anonfun$is$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(UAIParserTest.scala:24)
>     at
>   vultura.fastfactors.UAIParserTest$$anonfun$is$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(UAIParserTest.scala:24)

Comment: Sorry for seeing this question only now, the SO email ended up in my spam box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the `throwA[E]` matcher should be improved to display the expectable description when using `aka`. I'll fix this but as a work-around you can write:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {  def is =
  "parse all example uai files" ! {
    Seq("a", "b") must contain { (p: String) =>
      s"$p is ok" ==> { { sys.error("bang"); p} must not (throwAn[Exception]) }
    }.forall
  }
}
```

This displays:

```
[info] x parse all example uai files
[error]  There is 1 failure
[error]  a is not ok because Got the exception java.lang.RuntimeException: bang
```

Comment: Totally OT: Are you planning to do Specs3 some day, or are you happy with Specs2? As a long-term user of Specs2, I have the impression that there is still some room for improvement, in particular in the direction of a better DSL for creating and combining matchers. Too often I have to implement matchers from scratch where I feel it should be a simple combination of existing matchers.

Comment: I'm currently working on simplifying the internal implementation and better layering the dsls on top of an internal API. I might be able to improve matcher combinations and I'm opened to ideas if you have any.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your hard work- if possible, some of us would love a non-DSL yet scala idiomatic testing way, a la xUnit... or scalatest- FunSpec

Comment: And if possible limit the number of DSL's too so that newbies don't get confused on new syntax on every google search :-)